# SharePoint send notification Email After Assigning

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I created in SharePoint a list. with column Assigned To. What I want is that an email is sent to the Assignee, if the Assignee is added to this column. But the problem is that Workflow is started only automatically if any changes are made in an element or when an element is created.

So my question is, is there a possibility to trigger an email by content changes in a specified column without sending 2 emails.

Answer (score 0):

I think, If you are using SharePoint 2010 or 2013 workflow then you can set workflow to triger only for create and edit of item of list. But If you use Microsoft flow, you can trigger flow base on column change. But if you want to implement into 2010 and 2013 workflow then below step will work.
1) create one extra field and make it read only and hidden for every one.
2) trigger the workflow when item change into list.
3) if Assigned field is not null and not equal to extra field then send email and make extra field value same as Assigned field value.